# find out array key in session is already exists

Tags: php

I have session like this

```
$id = 'A001'
$_SESSION['cart'][$id]
```

And it contain value like below

```
Array
(
    [A001] => Array
        (
            [path] => product-details.html
            [img] => images/product/3.jpg
            [size] => 12 x 1.5 L
            [price] => 8.8
            [quantity] => 1
            [total] => 8.8
        )
)
```

**How can I find out whether this $_SESSION['cart'][id is existed]???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
    // its set...
}
```

Comment: it's always return true

Comment: If it's not set it won't return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])
```

This will give you a boolean indicating if the variable is set.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php